# Looping through rows in an R data frame?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe

I'm working with multiple big data frames in R and I'm trying to write functions that can modify each of them (given a set of common parameters). One function is giving me trouble (shown below).

```
RawData <- function(x)
{
  for(i in 1:nrow(x))
  {
    if(grep(".DERIVED", x[i,]) >= 1)
    {
      x <- x[-i,]
    }
  }
  for(i in 1:ncol(x))
  {
    if(is.numeric(x[,i]) != TRUE)
    {
      x <- x[,-i]
    }
  }
  return(x)
}
```

The objective of this function is twofold: first, to remove any rows that contain a ".DERIVED" string in any one of their cells (using grep), and second, to remove any columns that are non-numeric (using is.numeric). I get an error on the following condition:

```
if(grep(".DERIVED", x[i,]) >= 1)
```

The error states the "argument is of zero length", which I believe is usually associated with NULL values in a vector. However, I've used is.null on the entire data frame that is giving me errors, and it confirmed that there are no null values in the DF. I'm sure I'm missing something relatively simple here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: be careful removing rows in a `for-loop`, in your first `for` and `if` statement, you'll end up removing rows of `x` and then looping over the indices of the original rows, which will be an invalid index. It's also helpful to share example data if at all possible (and your desired outcome)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use non-base-R functions, this should address your issue. `df` is the `data.frame` in question here. It will also be faster than looping over rows (generally not advised if avoidable).

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  filter_all(!str_detect(., '\\.DERIVED')) %>%
  select_if(is.numeric)
```

You can make it a function just as you would anything else:

```
mattsFunction <- function(dat){
  dat %>%
    filter_all(!str_detect(., '\\.DERIVED')) %>%
    select_if(is.numeric)
}
```

you should probably give it a better name though

Comment: Is there a way I could turn this into a function, so I could easily call it on multiple data frames?

Comment: Yes, just as you would anything else. I've edited the post to create a function.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from the line

```
if(grep(".DERIVED", x[i,]) >= 1)
```

When grep doesn't find the term ".DERIVED", it returns something of zero length, your inequality doesn't return TRUE or FALSE, but rather returns `logical(0)`. The error is telling you that the `if` statement cannot evaluate whether `logical(0) >= 1`

A simple example:

```
if(grep(".DERIVED", "1234.DERIVEDabcdefg") >= 1) {print("it works")} # Works nicely, since the inequality can be evaluated
if(grep(".DERIVED", "1234abcdefg") > 1) {print("no dice")}
```

You can replace that line with `if(length(grep(".DERIVED", x[i,])) != 0)`

There's something else you haven't noticed yet, which is that you're removing rows/columns in a loop. Say you remove the 5th column, the next loop iteration (when i = 6) will be handling what *was* the 7th row! (this will end in an error along the lines of `Error in`[.data.frame`(x, , i) : undefined columns selected`)

Comment: The length fix works! Thanks. You're also spot-on with the indexing error, haha. Is there a way around it, or is it just a bad idea to use for-loops to remove vectors in a data frame?

Comment: @MattGreenig I would definitely look for another way

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using dplyr, but if you need to use base R functions there are ways to to this without if statements.

Notice that you should consider using the regex version of `"\\.DERIVED"` and not `".DERIVED"` which would mean "any character followed by DERIVED".

I don't have example data or output, so here's my best go...

```
# Made up data
test <- data.frame(a = c("data","data.DERIVED","data","data","data.DERIVED"),
                   b = (c(1,2,3,4,5)),
                   c = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                   d = c(2,5,6,8,9),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Note: The following code assumes that the column class is numeric because the
# example code provided assumed that the column class was numeric. This will not 
# detects if the column is full of a string of character values of only numbers.

# Using the base subset command
test2 <- subset(test,
                subset = !grepl("\\.DERIVED",test$a),
                select = sapply(test,is.numeric))

# > test2
#   b d
# 1 1 2
# 3 3 6
# 4 4 8


# Trying to use []. Note: If only 1 column is numeric this will return a vector
# instead of a data.frame
test2 <- test[!grepl("\\.DERIVED",test$a),]
test2 <- test2[,sapply(test,is.numeric)]

# > test2
#   b d
# 1 1 2
# 3 3 6
# 4 4 8
```